# variable didnt change in android acticity

Tags: android

I have this code for my activity in android project (I've simplified it) :

public class Favorites extends Activity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

```
public static int[] b;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    favorites_total_number = 0;
    // some code for change the favorites_total_number value

    b = new int[favorites_total_number];
    // some code for change values of b

 }

Globals global = new Globals(this);
public Integer[] mImageIds = global.build_favorite_list(b,favorites_total_number); 
// in previous line, b is not changed (but in onCreate method, I changed it)
```

}

I have changed the b in the onCreate method, but when i use the b (in the last line), It has not changed.
I can not write code for onCreate method elsewhere (There must be written, because part of the code only runs in onCreate method).
What should I do to change ?

The full code :

public class Favorites extends Activity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

```
public static int[] b;
public static int favorites_total_number;

// final SharedPreferences shared2 = this.getSharedPreferences("Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // show on gallery
    final SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    favorites_total_number = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x < 401; x = x+1) {  // change for develope
        String each_subject = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
        Boolean channel = shared.getBoolean(each_subject, false);
        if(channel){
            favorites_total_number = favorites_total_number + 1;
        }
    }
    b = new int[favorites_total_number];
    int p=-1;
    for(int x = 1; x < 401; x = x+1) {  // change for develope
        String each_subject = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
        Boolean channel = shared.getBoolean(each_subject, false);
        if(channel){
            p=p+1;
            b[p] = x;
        }
    }
    // String str = String.valueOf(favorites_total_number);
    String str = String.valueOf(b[1]);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // --

    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);


    mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
     mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
     mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             android.R.anim.fade_in));
     mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             android.R.anim.fade_out));

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
     g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
     g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
 }

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
 }

public View makeView() {
     ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
     i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
     i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
     i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
     return i;
 }

private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

    public int getCount() {
         return mThumbIds.length;
     }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
     }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cartoon_1);
        return i;
     }

    private Context mContext;

}

// int[] b_0={1,2,3,5,6};
// int favorites_total_number_0=5;
Globals global = new Globals(this);
private Integer[] all_images = global.favorite_images_0;  
public Integer[] mThumbIds = global.build_favorite_list(all_images,b,favorites_total_number);    
public Integer[] mImageIds = global.build_favorite_list(all_images,b,favorites_total_number);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've posted, it looks like this line

```
public Integer[] mImageIds = global.build_favorite_list(b,favorites_total_number);
```

is outside of `onCreate()` or any other method, which means it will run before `onCreate()` (where you change the value of `b`. Try to move that inside your `onCreate()` and see if you get what you want.

```
public static int[] b;
public Integer[] mImageIds;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    favorites_total_number = 0;
    // some code for change the favorites_total_number value

    b = new int[favorites_total_number];
    // some code for change values of b

   // moved the below lines inside onCreate()
   Globals global = new Globals(this);
   mImageIds = global.build_favorite_list(b,favorites_total_number);
 }
```

Comment: The code is complicated and i cant change the position of that line (Some other code will be corrupted).

Comment: Is that line outside of any method like I thought? If so, it **will** run before anything in `onCreate()`. You will need to explain why other code "will be corrupted" if you want help on how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wrote the complete code (update of post), you can see its structure.

Comment: What does it screw up and how if you declare and intialize `mImageIds` as I have above?

Comment: Your advice was correct, it works and there is no problem (I tested it). thank you codeMagic.